# String Reversal Memory Consumption Differences

Tags: c++, string, recursion, space-complexity

Suppose I implement the following two string reversal algorithms:

```
void reverse(string &s) {
  if(s.size() == 1) return;
  string restOfS = s.substr(1);
  reverse(restOfS);
  s = restOfS + s.at(0);
}

string reverseString(string s) {
    if(s.size() == 1) return s;
    return reverseString(s.substr(1)) + s.at(0);
}

int main() {
    string name = "Dominic Farolino";
    reverse(name);
    cout << name << endl;
    name = reverseString(name);
    cout << name << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

One of these obviously modifies the string given to it, and one of returns a new string. Since the first one modifies the given string and uses a reference parameter as its mode of communication to the next recursive stack frame, I at first assumed this would be more efficient since using a reference parameter may help us not duplicate things in memory down the line, however I don't believe that's the case. Obviously we have to use a reference parameter with this `void` function, but it seems that we are undoing any memory efficiency using a reference parameter may give us since we since we are just declaring a new variable on the stack every time.

In short, it seems that the first one is making a copy of the reference every call, and the second one is making a copy of the value each call and just returning its result, making them of equal memory consumption.

To make the first one more memory efficient I feel like you'd have to do something like this:

```
void reverse(string &s) {
  if(s.size() == 1) return;
  reverse(s.substr(1));
  s = s.substr(1) + s.at(0);
}
```

however the compiler won't let me:

`error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::string& {aka std::basic_string<char>&}' from an rvalue of type 'std::basic_string<char>'
6:6: note: in passing argument 1 of 'void reverse(std::string&)'`

Is this analysis correct?

Comment: This is not C. Please remove tag.

Comment: `substr` returns a copy - each of these approaches effectively has the same memory requirements.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth ok thanks, so that means the last line of the first one could not be (`s = s.substr(1) + s.at(0);`) because the original `s` is left unchanged?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Additionally, this means it is impossible recursively reverse a std::string with O(1) extra memory correct? If we used C, we could pass a pointer and run up to as many characters as we wanted to simulate our `substr`.

Comment: It's not possible, but for different reasons - you need O(n) recursive calls, therefore you'll need O(n) memory for the call stack.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth makes sense, however for that we would technically need to recurse at all correct? Could just implement it as a pure iterative solution (for loop with condition `i < length/2`

Comment: Why not use iterators instead of substrings? http://ideone.com/xQIJMM

Comment: @DomFarolino - Of course, just iterate from 0 to N/2, and swap x[i] with x[N-1-i].

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Oh yeah forgot about the stack frame memory...duhh

Comment: @kfsone yes any solution using iterators or iteration is going to be more efficient I was just trying to look more closely at the recursive implementation

Answer (score 3):

[`substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) returns a *new* string every time, complete with all the memory use that goes with that. So if you're going to do `N-1` calls to `substr()`, that's `O(N^2)` extra memory you're using for no reason.

With `std::string` though, you can modify it in place, just by iterating over it with a simple `for` loop. Or just using [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse):

```
void reverseString(string &s) {
    std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
}
```

Either way (`for` loop or algorithm) takes `O(1)` extra memory instead - it effectively is just a series of `swap`s, so you just need one extra `char` as the temporary. Much better.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah the best solution you can get with this is an iterative swapping necessary characters, I was just curious as to the exact memory consumption of the recursive implementations for the sake of theory I guess

Comment: @DomFarolino Same way you'd do it iteratively... swap a pair of `char`s, and then call down with tighter bounds.